# convert ffrom 16.0 version vi into 15.0 vi labview vi

Tags: labview

please help me to convert 16.0 vi into 15.0 version vi.  coulnt possible to open 16 version in 15 labview please help me with this .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save as to older version from File menu. 
This is not a question for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your statement, *"coulnt possible to open 16 version in 15 labview,"* it sounds like you have a specific VI (or set of VIs) that you need to open.

Find a colleague with LabVIEW 2016 and ask them to [save it](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvhowto/saving_for_the_previous_ve/) for LabVIEW 2015. Or, [ask a stranger](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Version-Conversion/bd-p/VersionConversion) to do so in NI's forums.

## Saving for Older Versions of LabVIEW

In general, you can write a LabVIEW program to do this for you with the [`Save For Previous`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvprop/vi_save_for_previous/) method in VI server.

#### Example

[image]

Keep in mind, however, that different LabVIEW file types have different **Save** methods, so you will need to detect the file type to use the correct method.

#### Save for Previous (by type)

Search the **Class Browser** (in the *View* menu, select *Class Browser,* and click the magnifying glass icon) to see what methods you can use:

[image]